# Fluent UI - Select dropdown not scrolling content

Tags: angular, office-addins, fluent-ui

I'm using the v9 of the Fluent UI Web Components in an Angular application in an Word Add-in.
It's all working as expected, except for the `FluentSelect`
When expanded and the items don't fit on the screen, the content does not scroll, so the bottom items are not visible.

In the CodePen it is working as expected:
[image]
Instead, the main content scrolls, which is not what I want:
[image]

I have removed all custom styling in the app so I'm not sure why this is happening.

UPDATE: Upon checking in the dev console, I found out that in my case the variable "--max-height" was not set, while it was set in the CodePen.
When I add below CSS it works. Not sure why I have to manually set it, seems like a hack.

```
:root {
--max-height: 200px
}
```

HTML:

```
<fluent-select title="Select a section">
  <fluent-option value="1">Beginning</fluent-option>
  <fluent-option value="2">Middle</fluent-option>
  <fluent-option value="3">End</fluent-option>
  <fluent-option value="1">Beginning</fluent-option>
  <fluent-option value="2">Middle</fluent-option>
  <fluent-option value="3">End</fluent-option>
  <fluent-option value="1">Beginning</fluent-option>
  <fluent-option value="2">Middle</fluent-option>
  <fluent-option value="3">End</fluent-option>
  <fluent-option value="1">Beginning</fluent-option>
  <fluent-option value="2">Middle</fluent-option>
  <fluent-option value="3">End</fluent-option>
</fluent-select>
```